# PHP SLIM: api call returns 6x same array

Tags: php, mysql, slim

I am using php slim to generate API calls to receive data from my MySQL database.

```
//PHPSLIM
require '.././libs/Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();


$categories = new \Slim\Slim();
$categories = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();

$categories->get('/categories', function(){
    global $conn, $servername, $username, $password, $dbname;
    mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);
    mysql_select_db($dbname);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT `categoryName` FROM `category`");

    while($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
        $cat[] = $line[0];
    } 

    echoResponseCat(200, $cat);

});

function echoResponseCat($status_code, $response) {
    global $categories;
    $categories->status($status_code);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $categories->contentType('application/json');
    echo json_encode($response,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
}

$categories->run();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();

//GET ALL ORDERS
$app->get('/orders', function(){
...
}
```

When I surf to http://localhost/localsites/serf/wea/web/api/categories
I get the data in json but it gives me 6 times the array!

```
["Lattes","CC Blend","Ice tea","Frappes"]["Lattes","CC Blend","Ice tea","Frappes"]["Lattes","CC Blend","Ice tea","Frappes"]["Lattes","CC Blend","Ice tea","Frappes"]["Lattes","CC Blend","Ice tea","Frappes"]["Lattes","CC Blend","Ice tea","Frappes"]
```

How is this coming and how can it be solved?

Comment: I found the problem but I think it's kinda weird: I am using the same approach as with $categories here in the code sample for 2 others. When the 3 of them are operationable I get this array 6 times but when I put the other 2 in comment, I do get the desired result... If anyone knows how this is possbile please advice!

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
// while($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
while($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
```

Comment: try `var_dump($cat);` to make sure the output is correct there.